# How to redirect AWS S3 sync output to a file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

When I run, AWS S3 SYNC "local drive" "S3bucket", I see bunch of logs getting generated on my aws cli console. Is there a way to direct these logs to an output/log file for future reference?

I am trying to schedule a sql job which executes the powershell script that syncs backup from local drive to S3 bucket. Backups are getting synched to the bucket successfully. However, I am trying to figure out a way to direct the sync progress to an output file. Help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Simply pipe the output of the command into a file using the ">" symbol.

The file does not have to exist before hand (and in-fact will be overwritten if it does exist).

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket > log.txt
```

If you wish to append to the given file then use the following operator: ">>".

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket >> existingLogFile.txt
```

To test this command, you can use the `--dryrun` argument to the `sync` command:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket --dryrun > log.txt
```

Comment: When I tried above, I get this : aws: error: too few arguments

Comment: AWS S3 SYNC "backupath" "S3bucketname" > log.txt  The log.txt file is getting created but its empty and I get too few arguments error in aws cli.

Comment: Did you use `s3://S3bucketname`? If you run it without the `> log.txt`, does it work?

Comment: Yes, I used s3 bucket url and sync works fine. My .bak files are getting synced to the bucket without any issue. I am looking for a way to direct the sync output which I see in aws cli to a log/output file. ex, upload: test.txt to s3://mybucket/test.txt
upload: test2.txt to s3://mybucket/test2.txt

Comment: if you get the redirect correct, it shows the progress and you get nothing but a shaz-ton of noise. Is there any way to turn off the % progress for logging?

Comment: ok, found it --no-progress flag makes for a much prettier log. It will still show the filename when complete.